# Python package build works, but the zip in dist does not have all files

Tags: python, packaging, pypi

The build of my daysgrounded package works fine with the command

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wininst bdist_egg bdist_wheel
```

in my dist dir appear these files:

```
daysgrounded-0.0.10.win32.exe
daysgrounded-0.0.10.zip
daysgrounded-0.0.10-py2.7.egg
daysgrounded-0.0.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

The egg and whl have all the text files inside the daysgrounded dir, but the zip does not. It only contains the source code py files.
This is the setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function,
                        unicode_literals)

##import sys
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
#import py2exe
##from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

from daysgrounded.globalcfg import NAME, VERSION, DATA_FILES
from daysgrounded import (DESC, LICENSE, URL, KEYWORDS, CLASSIFIERS, #PACKAGES,
                          ENTRY_POINTS, PKG_DATA)

AUTHOR = 'Joao Matos'
SCRIPT = NAME + '\\__main__.py'

### cx_Freeze config for bdist_msi
##bdist_msi_options = {
##    'upgrade_code': '{66620F3A-DC3A-11E2-B341-002219E9B01E}',
##    'add_to_path': False,
##    'initial_target_dir': r'[ProgramFilesFolder]\%s\%s' % (AUTHOR, NAME),
##    }
##build_exe_options = {'includes': ['atexit', 'PySide.QtNetwork']}
### GUI applications require a different base on Windows
##base = None
##if sys.platform == 'win32':
##    base = 'Win32GUI'
##exe = Executable(script=SCRIPT, base=base) #, icon='daysgrounded.ico')

setup(name=NAME,
      version=VERSION,
      description=DESC,
      long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
      #long_description=(read('README.txt') + '\n\n' +
      #                  read('CHANGES.txt') + '\n\n' +
      #                  read('AUTHORS.txt')),
      license=LICENSE,
      url=URL,
      author=AUTHOR,
      author_email='jcrmatos@gmail.com',

      keywords=KEYWORDS,
      classifiers=CLASSIFIERS,

      packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests*']),
      #packages=PACKAGES,

      # to create the Scripts exe using bdist_wininst build option
      entry_points=ENTRY_POINTS,

      install_requires=open('requirements.txt').read(),
      #install_requires=open('requirements.txt').read().splitlines(),

      include_package_data=True,
      package_data=PKG_DATA,

      # py2exe config
      #console=[SCRIPT],
      #data_files=DATA_FILES,

##      # cx_Freeze config for bdist_msi
##      executables=[exe],
##      options={'bdist_msi': bdist_msi_options, 'build_exe': build_exe_options}
     )
```

this is the

```
__init__.py

#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

"""Manage child(s) grounded days."""

from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function,)
                        #unicode_literals)
# The above unicode_literals import prevents setup.py from working.
# It seems to be a bug in setuptools.

import sys
from os import path

sys.path.insert(1, path.dirname(__file__)) # add path to PYTHONPATH

__all__ = ['DESC', 'LICENSE', 'URL', 'KEYWORDS', 'CLASSIFIERS', #'PACKAGES',
           'ENTRY_POINTS', 'PKG_DATA']

DESC = __doc__.strip()
LICENSE = 'GNU General Public License v2 or later (GPLv2+)'
URL = 'https://github.com/jcrmatos/DaysGrounded'
KEYWORDS = 'days grounded'
CLASSIFIERS = [# Use below to prevent any unwanted publishing
               #'Private :: Do Not Upload'
               'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
               'Environment :: Console',
               'Environment :: Win32 (MS Windows)',
               'Intended Audience :: End Users/Desktop',
               'Intended Audience :: Developers',
               'Natural Language :: English',
               'Natural Language :: Portuguese',
               'License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v2 or later (GPLv2+)',
               'Operating System :: OS Independent',
               'Programming Language :: Python',
               'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
               'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
               'Topic :: Other/Nonlisted Topic']

#PACKAGES = ['daysgrounded']

ENTRY_POINTS = {
    'console_scripts': ['daysgrounded = daysgrounded.__main__:main'],
    #'gui_scripts': ['app_gui = daysgrounded.daysgrounded:start']
    }

PKG_DATA = {'daysgrounded': ['usage.txt', 'LICENSE.txt', 'banner.txt']}
#PKG_DATA= {'': ['*.txt'], 'daysgrounded': ['*.txt']}
```

and this is the globalcfg.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

"""Global configuration."""

from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function,)
                        #unicode_literals)
                        # ToDo: fix strings to activate above import?

USAGE_FILE = 'usage.txt'
#USAGE_FILE = 'usage_en.txt'
BANNER_FILE = 'banner.txt'
#BANNER_FILE = 'banner_en.txt'
LICENSE_FILE = 'LICENSE.txt'

NAME = 'daysgrounded'
VERSION = '0.0.10'
COPYRIGHT = 'Copyright 2014 Joao Matos'

DATA_FILES = [('', [NAME + '\\' + USAGE_FILE]),
              ('', [NAME + '\\' + BANNER_FILE]),
              ('', [NAME + '\\' + LICENSE_FILE])]
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `MANIFEST.in` file that tells `setup` which additional files to distribute.  The [Distributing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute) section of the documentation describes how to do this.

Comment: Hello, According to the docs you indicate (which I had read) it should have worked with the package_data metadata in the setup.py (which was in place), but apparently it doesn't. I added the same items to the MANIFEST.in and it worked. Thanks.